# Upgrading to jdk 1.7 on linux, Getting Error

Tags: java, linux

Already `jdk1.6` is installed on `linux` server, when I try to upgrade the version to `1.7` getting the below error:

> file /etc/init.d/jexec from install of jdk-1.7.0_79-fcs.x86_64
>   conflicts
>       with file from package jdk-1.6.0_25-fcs.x86_64.

Ran this command:

```
 rpm -Uvh /usr/java/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.rpm
```

Need help...

Comment: Use the --force flag to install multiple versions.

Comment: not sure which distribution you're using but I would go with apt-get or yum installation and configure alternatives so you can easily select which version you want to run

Comment: @FredericHenri Most likely Fedora. rpm is the yum/apt-get for RedHat.

Comment: @m0skit0 Fedora uses yum, rpm is just the base level package manager under it.

Answer (score 1):

You already have JDK 6 installed. Uninstall it first.

```
rpm -e jdk-1.6.0_25-fcs.x86_64
```

Comment: Isn't there any way I can keep both the versions?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with RPM-based distros (last one I used was RedHat 8 IIRC), but why you want both? You can target 1.6 using JDK 1.7.

Comment: can you run `alternatives --config java` as root it will propose you the different versions of java you have installed

Comment: True that, I've even done it. But in the end, it's not worth the mess, you can just stick with the latest one unless you have a strong reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Uninstall the jdk6 and install the newest, or Download manually the new jdk, and extract it in a folder from your choice and after this fix the PATH variable, by making the value of your folder before all other entries,

```
$export PATH="jdkFolder:$PATH"
```

you can test if the change was made, by typing

```
$whereis javac
```

or

```
$whereis java
```

if the path point to your new folder that means you come to install your jdk manually with success.
finaly you add this line at the and of your ~/.bashrc file.

```
export PATH="<your_jdkFolder>:$PATH"
```